# Receiving an error when executing a stored procedure that calls a linked server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am in the process of setting up dynamic Reporting Services Shared Data Source using Linked Server. In doing so, I have created a stored procedure that requires a parameter and in testing the stored procedure (before setting everything else in SSRS) I am receiving an error. The stored Procedure code looks like this:

```
     create procedure [dbo].[SelectFromServer3]

    @ServerName sysname

 as
 begin

    set nocount on;

     declare @sql nvarchar(max)

  set @sql = N'Select * from ' + quotename(@ServerName)+ '               
 .remotesvrnm.dbo.CUSTOMERS_DISAM_TABLE'

  exec sp_executesql @sql

 end
```

When I execute the following query to test the stored procedure:

```
    EXEC SelectFromServer3 @ServerName = 'SQLSVRInstanceNM'
```

I receive the following error:

"Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'remotesvrnm.dbo.CUSTOMERS_DISAM_TABLE'."

However, if I query the linked server directly with a query like:

```
  EXEC ('SELECT * from remotesvrnm.dbo.CUSTOMERS_DISAM_TABLE') AT LNKDSRVRNM
```

The data is returned as expected. Even using an openquery statement works as expected:

```
    Select * from openquery (LNKDSRVRNM, 'select * from remotesvrnmdbo.CUSTOMERS_DISAM_TABLE')
```

The guide that I am using to set this up I pulled from a Web search. I am at a loss as to how to resolve this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a line break character after you concantenate the servername?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @PaulHoke for the suggestion to add  to the stored procedure. I found that I had two things wrong... I found that I was missing a space in my stored procedure code. I was missing a space between the single quote and the .remotesvrnm.dbo.CUST....'.

The second issue was that when executing the stored procedure, I needed to use the name of the linked server, not the SQL Server Instance name. --The guide that I have been following, that I found on-line, was poorly written.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also did not have "Level Zero only" unchecked for the provider that I am using for my linked server (which was causing a slightly different error when executing the stored procedure.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use print @sql in your stored procedure to see what it evaluates to?  Paste that into a new query window and see if you get the same error.  If yes, please paste it here.

The code as shown works perfectly for me.